# Run more than one server using python

Tags: python, server

I am basically trying to run two servers using a simple script. I have used the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954549/how-can-i-run-2-servers-at-once-in-python), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258616/running-two-process-simultaneously) and others.
For instance in the example below I am trying to host two directories in ports 8000 and 8001.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import os
import multiprocessing


def run_webserver(path, PORT):
    os.chdir(path)
    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', PORT), Handler)

    httpd.serve_forever()

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Define "services" directories and ports to use to host them
    server_details = [
        ("path/to/directory1", 8000),
        ("path/to/directory2", 8001)
    ]

    # Run servers
    servers = []
    for s in server_details: 
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=run_webserver, 
            args=(s[0], s[1])
            )
        servers.append(p)  

    for server in servers:
        server.start()

    for server in servers:
        server.join()
```

Once I execute the code below it all works fine and I can access both directories using http://localhost:8000 and http://localhost:8001. However, when I exit the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then try to run the script again I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                     
 "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap           
        self.run()                                                                                                         
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run                   
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                                                                          
      File "repos/scripts/webhosts.py", line 12, in run_webserver                                                          
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__                        
        self.server_bind()                                                                                                 
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind                     
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)                                                                              
    OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This error only pops up if I actually access the server when running. If I do not access to it, I can re-run the script... From the error message it looks like there is something still accessing the server when typing `lsof -n -i4TCP:8000` and `lsof -n -i4TCP:8001` I don't get anything... And after a while this error stops appearing and I can actually run the script.

Comment: Question? What happens inside `exit_handler`? Are you by any chance calling `shutdown` or `server_close`?

Comment: Ups, sorry, I was trying to use that before but I did not manage to make it work and I forgot to remove (I just updated the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting the server, add:

```
socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
```

or change that attribute of the instance, again before calling `serve_forever()`:

```
htttp.allow_reuse_address = True
```

---

[Documentation reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.allow_reuse_address):

> `BaseServer.allow_reuse_address`
>
> Whether the server will allow the reuse of an address. This defaults to False, and can be set in subclasses to change the policy.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

In a previous edit OP registered an exit handler `atexit.register(exit_handler)`. The question is, does it cleans your systems resources (a.k.a open sockets)?

If your program exits without closing the sockets (because you interrupted it with Ctrl+C) it make take some time for the OS clean up the sockets (cause they're in TIME_WAIT state), you can read about TIME_WAIT and how to avoid it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592747/bind-error-while-recreating-socket).

Using exit handlers is a good way to avoid this

```
import atexit
atexit.register(clean_sockets)

def clean_sockets():
    mysocket.server_close() #
```